# Am I using Q correctly with Durandal, KO, and Breeze?

Tags: knockout.js, breeze, durandal, q

Longtime .NET developer just now building my first ever web application.   I am attempting to use Durandal, Breeze, and Knockout which I think I understand architecturally.  However, this doesn't change the fact that I feel like I just landed in a foreign country with some of the basic notions of jQuery.

I am having trouble with async programing, using the notion of promises, with Q.  Ordinarily one would have an 'activate' handler for Durandal in the KO viewmodel with a function like,

```
var activate = function() {
    return ebodatacontext.getOrganizations(organizations);
};
```

where a call is made to the Breeze datacontext to get data from an entity over the api and the 'organizations' is a ko.observableArray. In my app, this works fine.

However, in my case my view has two lists of entities so I need two calls to the datacontext which I put together with Q like this:

```
var activate = function() {
    var promise =
        Q.all([
            ebodatacontext.getOrganizations(organizations),
            ebodatacontext.getUserRoles(userRoles)
        ]);
    return promise;
};
```

As far as I can see, either of those datacontext calls work on their own and bind ok to the view.  But when I Q them, like this, only the first one seems to work.  I fear I am missing something basic here.

I can see in the network traffic that both api calls are made for the two sets of entities.  And good results come back over the network.

However, it seems that the ko.observable  (userRoles) for the second call does not end up with any data.    If I swap the order of them, in the Q array, the first one works.  It seems to me like I have neglected something here and the binding is taking place too soon or something.

If my use of Q is correct here, I will assume that I have more debugging to do elsewhere. Thanks in advance.

Here is the ebodatacontext using Breeze:

```
define([
    'durandal/system',
    'services/ebomodel',
    'config',
    'services/logger'],
    function (system, ebomodel, config, logger) {

        var EntityQuery = breeze.EntityQuery;
        var manager = configureBreezeManager();
        var orderBy = ebomodel.orderBy;
        var entityNames = ebomodel.entityNames;

        var getOrganizations = function(organizationsObservable, forceRemote) {
            if (!forceRemote) {
                var p = getLocal('Organizations', orderBy.Name);
                if (p.length > 0) {
                    organizationsObservable(p);
                    return Q.resolve();
                }
            }

            var query = EntityQuery.from('Organizations')
                //.orderBy(orderBy.Name)
                ;

            return manager.executeQuery(query)
                .then(querySucceeded)
                .fail(queryFailed);

            function querySucceeded(data) {
                if (organizationsObservable) {
                    organizationsObservable(data);
                }
                log('Retrieved [Organizations] from remote data source',
                    data, true);
            }
        };

        var getUserRoles = function(rolesObservable, forceRemote) {
            if (!forceRemote) {
                var p = getLocal('UserRoles', orderBy.Name);
                if (p.length > 0) {
                    rolesObservable(p);
                    return Q.resolve();
                }
            }

            var query = EntityQuery.from('UserRoles')
              //  .orderBy(orderBy.Name)
                ;

            return manager.executeQuery(query)
                .then(querySucceeded)
                .fail(queryFailed);

            function querySucceeded(data) {
                if (rolesObservable) {
                    rolesObservable(data);
                }
                log('Retrieved [UserRoles] from remote data source',
                    data, true);
            }
        };

        var cancelChanges = function() {
            manager.rejectChanges();
            log('Canceled changes', null, true);
        };

        var saveChanges = function() {
            return manager.saveChanges()
                .then(saveSucceeded)
                .fail(saveFailed);

            function saveSucceeded(saveResult) {
                log('Saved data successfully', saveResult, true);
            }

            function saveFailed(error) {
                var msg = 'Save failed: ' + error.message;
                logError(msg, error);
                error.message = msg;
                throw error;
            }
        };

        var primeData = function () {
         };

        var createOrganization = function() {
            return manager.createEntity(entityNames.organization);
        };

        var createUserRole = function() {
            return manager.createEntity(entityNames.role);
        };

        var hasChanges = ko.observable(false);

        manager.hasChangesChanged.subscribe(function(eventArgs) {
            hasChanges(eventArgs.hasChanges);
        });

        var ebodatacontext = {
            createOrganization: createOrganization,
            createUserRole: createUserRole,
            getOrganizations: getOrganizations,
            getUserRoles: getUserRoles,
            hasChanges: hasChanges,
            primeData: primeData,
            cancelChanges: cancelChanges,
            saveChanges: saveChanges
        };

        return ebodatacontext;

        //#region Internal methods        

        function getLocal(resource, ordering, includeNullos) {
            var query = EntityQuery.from(resource)
 //               .orderBy(ordering)
                ;
            //if (!includeNullos) {
            //    query = query.where('id', '!=', 0);
            //}
            return manager.executeQueryLocally(query);
        }

        function queryFailed(error) {
            var msg = 'Error retreiving data. ' + error.message;
            logger.logError(msg, error, system.getModuleId(ebodatacontext), true);
            throw error;
        }

        function configureBreezeManager() {
            breeze.NamingConvention.camelCase.setAsDefault();
            var mgr = new breeze.EntityManager(config.eboRemoteServiceName);
            ebomodel.configureMetadataStore(mgr.metadataStore);
            return mgr;
        }

        function log(msg, data, showToast) {
            logger.log(msg, data, system.getModuleId(ebodatacontext), showToast);
        }
        //#endregion
});
```

Comment: Your Q call looks correct. Are the `get` methods returning results, or promises?

Comment: As @Tyrsius is implying, it'd help us if we had a better understanding of what the return value of your `getOrganizations` and `getUserRoles` functions are. If we can see an example that would help a lot ... as it stands, we don't have much more to go on.

Comment: I added the ebocontext code.  Thanks for the help, everyone.

Comment: Sorry, I mean thanks in advance for the help.  My confusion is still outstanding (I get that a lot.).

Comment: Durandal docs say that Durandal uses jQuery promises so one has to apply a patch when using Q promises.   http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Q/ 

I did this and it did not help.

Comment: I discovered my problem.   It is obvious but not to a novice like me.   How do I answer my own question?

Comment: You can add an answer like anyone else and then, after a day or two, S.O. will let you mark it as THE answer. Additional thought: you should have a `.fail(...)` on your `Q.all([...])` to handle failures inside your interior promise callbacks; that's belt and suspenders. Also ... at some point you may want to make this a little DRYer and re-factor the common code in your query methods. But get it working first :-)

Comment: Ward, thanks for all the advice.  I am still getting used to scope and when things fire.  But I think I am ready to do some refactoring as you say.

In C# I am the DRYist person you can imagine.   I don't yet have the chops for jQuery, as this is my first few weeks using it.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the Durandal/Q "patch" refered in http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Q/ im facing the same issue and i can't figure out how to get Q to work with durandal

Answer (score 1):

I am answering my own question because I was way off base in thinking the  problem was due to Q and promises.   It seems I had that working ok.

All my problems were solved by realizing that in the Breeze datacontext, I needed to initialize the passed-in ko.observableArray with data.result, instead of data.

My broken code:

```
    var getOrganizations = function (organizationsObservable) {

        var query = EntityQuery.from('Organizations');

        return manager.executeQuery(query)
            .then(querySucceeded)
            .fail(queryFailed);

        function querySucceeded(data) {
            if (organizationsObservable) {
                organizationsObservable(data);
            }
            log('Retrieved [Organizations] from remote data source',
                data, true);
        }
    };
```

My code that works:

```
    var getOrganizations = function (organizationsObservable) {

        var query = EntityQuery.from('Organizations');

        return manager.executeQuery(query)
            .then(querySucceeded)
            .fail(queryFailed);

        function querySucceeded(data) {
            if (organizationsObservable) {
                organizationsObservable(data.results);
            }
            log('Retrieved [Organizations] from remote data source',
                data, true);
        }
    };
```

If you are as new to this as I am, the clue is that when you observe the contents of the returning ko.observableArray it should not be a single object of type XHR (uh duh).    The XHR that comes back from the API call to the controller has the actual date in the 'result' field.

Thanks everyone for putting up with a newbie trying to use all the latest technology for SPA client applications.

The good news is that although I am still somewhat clueless about some of the basics, I am well on my way for having a rich client with full data lifecycle and navigation, that looks like a professional site (thanks to bootstrap).

I would like to give a shoutout to John Papa's Pluralsight course and blog article on SPA applications with his Hot Towel template.

http://www.johnpapa.net/hottowel/